# Error loading JQuery from gem in Production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I'm trying to switch my application into production mode, but every time i start the server i get an internal Server Error (500).

The command i'm using:

```
thin start -p 2048 -e production --ssl --ssl-key-file ./mykey.key --ssl-cert-file ./mycert.crt
```

So i looked inside my log:

-> production.log

```
ActionView::Template::Error (jquery-1.7.1.min.js isn't precompiled):
3:  <head>
4:  <title>MSDNAA</title>
5:  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
6:  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.7.1.min.js" %>
7:      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
8:      <%= csrf_meta_tags if false %>
9:  </head>
```

Well i'm pretty new to Rails so i watched 2 Railscasts handling the assets-pipeline
([279](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) and [282](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1)) to make sure i understood everything.
When I'm understanding that correctly the things i have to do are the following:
Add the following lines to my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

That will include all the needed JQuery files, itself and all the JS-files in my assets directory.
Then I have to make sure that the JQuery-Rails gem is installed and included inside my Gemfile. I hit bundle to make sure it is used and evrything went fine.
Then i added the stuff explained in Rails Cast 282.
After that i have to precompile my assets using the following command:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

After that i still get that error. 
There is no need to load the jquery-1.7.1.min.js, it's not even inside my application directory.
The second thing i'm worried abot is that when i'm connecting to my app via browser like this:

```
https://myapp:2048/assets/application.js
```

I should see every JScript related stuff wrapped together. Instead i get a "404 - Page not found" error and the log says: "No route matches /[AppDir]/assets/javascripts/application.js"

What am i doing wrong?
Did i miss something? (I guess!)

Versioninfo:

Rails 3.2.8
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]